# Storing a date with two bytes

Tags: java, encoding, binary

I recently saw a talk about binary encoding and the example given was storing the date part (day, month and year) of a Java `Date` object in two bytes.  I'm now trying to understand the code snippet from the talk:

```
long time = new Date().getTime();  // time in ms since epoch
time /= 86400000; // ms in a day
byte a = (byte)(time >>> 8);
byte b = (byte)(time);
```

Now the bit I'm missing is how it's apparently "simple" to turn these two bytes back into the day, month and year of the original date.  I'm also not sure why we use two bytes if we retain the original time values as a byte as well.

Could someone please explain how that is possible?  I understand what the code above is doing, just not how it's possible to restore the original date.

**Update**

This is the talk, the slide in question is 20/21

http://www.slideshare.net/jtdavies/turn-your-xml-into-binary-java-one-2014

Comment: I can't understand your question. There is one single date here, not 2. And this transformation does not preserve the time.

Comment: I don't see any code that is building a `Date` from the two  `byte`s.

Comment: @JB Nizet - As stated, it's not about restoring the time, it is only required to restore the day, month and year.

Comment: This code also assumes that there are 86400000 ms in every day, which isn't true due to daylight savings.

Comment: @yshavit And leap seconds.

Comment: And I still don't understand your question. If your question is "why is it useful to use only 2 bytes for a date rather than 8?", then the answer is probably: because it's shorter and thus consumes less memory, disk space or bandwidth.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I don't understand your frustration, I'm asking a question on a site for asking questions.  I know the benefits of storing it as two bytes, I just don't see how it's possible to restore it.

Comment: Ah, so your question is: "how to get back a Date from these two bytes?". Why don't you ask that question then? What you ask is "Could someone please explain how that is useful?", which doesn't mean the same thing at all, does it?

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for you invaluable feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to restore the date from the bytes:

```
long time = new Date().getTime(); // time in ms since epoch
time /= 86400000; // ms in a day
byte a = (byte) (time >>> 8);
byte b = (byte) (time);

time = a;
time = time << 8;
time = time | b;
time *= 86400000;

System.out.println(new Date(time));
```

But, unfortunately, this will not always work, as days are not always 86400000 ms long, due to [daylight savings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: You beat me by 45s ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your `byte`s are 8-bit bytes then this provides a 16-bit range or `0-65535`.

A day number can be `1-31` which can fit into 5 bits.

A month number can be `1-12` which can fit into 4 bits.

This leaves `16-5-4=7` bits to store the year or a range of `0-127`. You can probably assume we are talking `2000` onwards so you can easily pack any date into a 16-bit number.

```
    int date = ((((y % 100) << 5) + m) << 4) + d;
    int year = 2000 + (date >>> (5 + 4));
    int month = (date >> 4) & 0x1f;
    int day = date & 0xf;
```

Be warned - this was the idea that cost the world billions (allegedly). It was called the [y2k bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) only back then we only added `1900`.

Comment: actually this doesn't answer to the question, but it's so simple and elegant I can just +1

Comment: The example has month and day mixed up. The correct code is:

    int date = (((y << 4) + m) << 5) + d;
    int year = 2000 + (date >> (5 + 4));
    int month = (date >> 5) & 0xf;
    int day = date & 0x1f;

Answer (score 2):

If you have the two bytes `a` and `b`, you can reconstruct the original timestamp like so:

```
public static Date reconstructFromBytes(byte a, byte b) {
    long timestampRecovered = (a << 8);
    timestampRecovered += b;
    timestampRecovered *= 86400000;

    return new Date(timestampRecovered);
}
```

As one of the commenters stated, this assumes that there are 86400000ms in a day.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
    long time = new Date().getTime();  // time in ms since epoch
    int days = (int) (time / 86400000); // number of days since 1970-01-01
    System.out.println("Number of days since epoch: " + days);
    System.out.println("As hex: " + Integer.toHexString(days));
    byte a = (byte)(days >>> 8); // get higher byte
    byte b = (byte)(days);       // get lower byte
    System.out.println("Hihger byte: " + Integer.toHexString(a));
    System.out.println("Lower byte: " + Integer.toHexString(b));
```

prints

```
Number of days since epoch: 16507
As hex number: 407b
Hihger byte: 40
Lower byte: 7b
```

Answer (score 0):

The slides you are talking about try to reduce the disk or bandwidth usage by saving data into a format which consumes less bytes.

The slides give this code example:

```
long time = new Date().getTime();  // time in ms since epoch
time /= 86400000; // ms in a day
byte a = (byte)(time >>> 8);
byte b = (byte)(time);
```

What that code snippet does is actually the following:

- it gets the timestamp from the `Date`;
- it then divides it by `86400000`,  because that is the number of milliseconds in a day, and we don't need any other information 'smaller' than days;
- it then stores the two remaining bytes into position 8 and 9 of an array named `data`.

In that way they strip away some information which they don't need; in this case all time units smaller than a day (hours, minutes, et cetera...).

We could save it into a `short`, which is two bytes:

```
short ourTime = (short) time;
```

but since the [example on the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/jtdavies/turn-your-xml-into-binary-java-one-2014) use a `byte[]`, it shifts the two bytes into position 8 and 9 of `data`.

#### Restoring the date

And restoring the date from those two bytes is just the other way around:

- one should get the two bytes (done by `wordFromBytesFromOffset(8)`, which picks the two bytes from the `data` array);
- then multiply by 86400000 to create a timestamp;
- using the `Date` constructor which accepts a timestamp.

As said, one of the `Date` constructors accepts a timestamp (of type `long`) as argument to construct the `Date` object. In order to do so, we must convert our two-byte date back to a full timestamp.

*Note that, due to the conversion, one cannot rely on the values of hours, minutes and seconds. So it's not exactly the original timestamp.*

Comment: Thanks - I had some comments around the context of my question.  I've tried to update the question to show that the part I was missing was the restoration of the date, rather than the usefulness of storing it as two bytes.